# Multiline text in a ListView (text cut off at the end)

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I've see this topic a few times but right now when I need it, I can't find it... I have a problem with a few ListView's in my app. The ListViews are displaying content from a database and from a webservice. The content of the ListView can be very large and sometimes, the text is cut off...

This is my ListView so far:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DataListView" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupData}" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortCategory}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
            IsGroupingEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="#b99f65" SeparatorColor="#55492e" ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped" Margin="0,3,0,0">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="#120305" Margin="0">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="15,0">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Category}" TextColor="#b99f65" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding ShortCategory, StringFormat='({0})'}" FontSize="18" TextColor="#b99f65" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,5" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0" />

                    <Label Text="{Binding Effect}" FontSize="11" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Margin="0" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Ingredients, StringFormat='Ingredients: {0}'}" FontSize="11" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Margin="0,3,0,0" SizeChanged="OnLabelSizeChanged" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here, the Ingredients are cut off in iOS on some device sizes. I have implemented a SizeChanged-Event for the last Label to see if the size is set correctly, and it is. This is the output:

```
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 26.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 26.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 13.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 13.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 26.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 13.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 26.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 13.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 26.5
[0:] LABEL HEIGHT CHANGED:: 13.5
```

Any of the "26.5" height labels are cut off in half. Because this only happens on iOS it must be a problem there. Can someone help me out to fix this? I have the same issue on other places of my App too and haven't found a working solution yet... I know I can set the RowHeight to the max possible value but for this I need to know how many times the text will be wraped and it is not a nice solution... I would like to use the dynamic sizing...

As a workaround I currently use this on the last Label in iOS, but it takes a huge amount of performance and looks very bad...

```
private void OnLabelSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stackLayout = (sender as Label)?.Parent as StackLayout;
    if (stackLayout != null)
    {
        var childrenHeight = stackLayout.Children.Sum(c => c.Height) + stackLayout.Children.Count * stackLayout.Spacing;
        stackLayout.HeightRequest = childrenHeight;

        var viewCell = stackLayout.Parent as ViewCell;
        viewCell?.ForceUpdateSize();
    }
}
```

And beside of the performance lost it also makes the app looks wrong if the device orientation changes.